# Draggable JS element not recentering on button click

Tags: javascript

I have the following JS code I am using to move something around on the screen and then when i click a button I want to move everything back to where the original element loaded. Why does my following logic not work? I have also tried subtracting the `gMouseDownOffsetX` and `gMouseDownOffsetY`  still the button does not transform the image back to the orgin of where it started.

I know the button works because it does in fact change other properties I set, but not the position.

```js
$('#clickMe').click(function(){

  $(#element).css({' transform : 'translate('+ -gMouseDownX + ')' });
  $(#element).css({' transform : 'translate(' + -gMouseDownY + ')' });
});







let gMouseDownX = 0;
let gMouseDownY = 0;
let gMouseDownOffsetX = 0;
let gMouseDownOffsetY = 0;

function addListeners() {
    document.getElementById('cursorImage').addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
}

function mouseUp() {
    window.removeEventListener('mousemove', divMove, true);
}

function mouseDown(e) {
    gMouseDownX = e.clientX;
    gMouseDownY = e.clientY;

    var div = document.getElementById('cursorImage');

    //The following block gets the X offset (the difference between where it starts and where it was clicked)
    let leftPart = "";
    if(!div.style.left)
        leftPart+="0px";    //In case this was not defined as 0px explicitly.
    else
        leftPart = div.style.left;
    let leftPos = leftPart.indexOf("px");
    let leftNumString = leftPart.slice(0, leftPos); // Get the X value of the object.
    gMouseDownOffsetX = gMouseDownX - parseInt(leftNumString,10);

    //The following block gets the Y offset (the difference between where it starts and where it was clicked)
    let topPart = "";
    if(!div.style.top)
        topPart+="0px";     //In case this was not defined as 0px explicitly.
    else
        topPart = div.style.top;
    let topPos = topPart.indexOf("px");
    let topNumString = topPart.slice(0, topPos);    // Get the Y value of the object.
    gMouseDownOffsetY = gMouseDownY - parseInt(topNumString,10);

    window.addEventListener('mousemove', divMove, true);
}

function divMove(e){
    var div = document.getElementById('cursorImage');
    div.style.position = 'absolute';
    let topAmount = e.clientY - gMouseDownOffsetY;
    div.style.top = topAmount + 'px';
    let leftAmount = e.clientX - gMouseDownOffsetX;
    div.style.left = leftAmount + 'px';
}

addListeners();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that your position is moved by setting top and left. Why not try to directly set the top and left values to the default values?

**Update:**

try this:

```js
$('#clickMe').click(function(){
  $("#cursorImage").css({ left: 0, top: 0});
});
```

Comment: can you explain what you mean, I mean what you are saying is clear, but I'm not following.

Comment: I updated the answer for you, please check it.

Comment: Thank you so much much. big help :)